# Does not contain a definition for 'where' and the best extension method overload

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've searched and found this error all over the stackoverflow forum, but it applies differently each time and I'd like someone help me in this particular matter.

```
public IEnumerable<Project> FindRange(string filterExpression, string sortingExpression, int startIndex, int count)
{
    try
    {
        using (BusinessContext context = new BusinessContext())
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterExpression))
                 return context.Projects
                               .Where(filterExpression)
```

The last line being the one of the error...

Do you have any idea why is this happening? I've already added all the usings and dlls needed, being:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
```

What am I missing? I've got code structured the same way, working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be trying to use the [Dynamic Linq](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) library. In that case you need to ensure that you've [added the NuGet package to your project](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog) and then include this namespace:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your filterexpression parameter should not be a `string` - it should be a `Func<>`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Hey, thanks. Can be a string if you are using the Dynamic Library!:)

Answer (score 1):

If your `BusinessContext` class has a string property such as Name that you are wanting to filter on then your where expression should look something like

```
.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(filterExpression.ToLower()))
```